# Can you use conditionals in JavaScript object literal definitions?

Tags: javascript

Can you use conditionals within a JavaScript object literal definition?

What I mean is, instead of:

```
if(flag)
{
    return { value1: getval(), value2: getval2()};
}
else
{
    return { value1: getval()};
}
```

Is there any way to do something like:

```
return { value1: getval(), flag?(value2: getval2())};
```

I know that I could do:

```
return { value1: getval(), value2: flag?getval2():null };
```

But that way, the member `value2` is defined regardless of the value of `flag`.

Comment: I think it's just an `Object`, not `json`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think you can do it neatly in one line but it would be easy enough to do something like this:

```
var json = { value1: getval() };
if (flag) json.value2 = getval2();
return json;
```

It's a few more lines but it also means that you don't have to repeat yourself.

---

If you really wanted to do this in one line and are already using underscore.js, then here's an alternative that uses [`_.extend()`](http://underscorejs.org/#extend):

```
return _.extend({ value1: getval() }, flag ? { value2: getval2() } : {});
```

It's marginally shorter but personally, I'd recommend the first approach.

Answer (score 0):

It is much simpler, just put the condition outside the object, instead of writing:

```
return { value1: getval(), flag?(value2: getval2())};
```

You will need:

```
return flag ? { value1: getval(), value2: getval2()} : { value1: getval()};
```

This is a simple DEMO:

```js
function test(flag) {
  return flag ? {value1: "value1", value2: "value2"} : {value1: "value1"};
}

console.log(test(true));
console.log(test(false));
```

The output is the following:

> test(true) --->  {value1: "value1" , value2: "value2"}
>
> test(false) ---> {value1: "value1"}

It uses the same logic as the if statement you were using in your question but with the **[Conditional ternary Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)** inside the return statement giving a one line solution.

Answer (score -1):

**UPDATE**

Okey, so if you want to set `value2` only if `flag == true`, do following:

```
var flag = false;

function getreturn() {
    var return_val = { value1: getval() };
    if (flag==true) { return_val.value2 = getval2() }
    return return_val;
}

function getval() {
    return "hello";
}

function getval2() {
    return "world";
}

console.log(getreturn());
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/omxqs61g/2/

This way you only set the `value2` if `flag == true` and let the var untouched, if it's false.

Also the answer is at this point: No, you can't do it.
The reason is quite simple: With `var name = {..}` you declaring an object with his parameters. This declaring has some rules and this short `if` checks are not within the rules.

I let the old answer here, maybe it can help anyone.

**OLD Answer**

(Not the way the OP wanted. Everything down here is from the old answer, even the Edit part)

Yes, you can.

Look at following code:

```
var flag = false;

function getreturn() {
    return { value1: getval(), value2: flag ? getval2() : null };
}

function getval() {
    return "hello";
}

function getval2() {
    return "world";
}

console.log(getreturn());
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/omxqs61g/1/

If `flag` is `true`, you will get:

`Object {value1: "hello", value2: "world"}`

otherwise you will get:

`Object {value1: "hello", value2: null}`

If you're not using a boolean for `flag`, you also can check if `typeof flag !== 'undefined'`, this should also work if it's not defined.

**EDIT**

I read the question again and I am not sure if I understood it right. If the real question is, if it's possible "not to set `value"` if `flag != true`, than I would recommend not doing this way!

Here my quote from my comment:

> I recommend not to do this way! I did this accidentally in my last project and regret this decision, because this way it's way to unconsistent and will lead to harder work in the future. Better always set value2 and check if it's value2 != null

Comment: Wait.. do you want that `value2` is NOT SET when `flag` is `false` ?? I recommend not to do this way! I did this accidentally in my last project and regret this decision, because this way it's way to unconsistent and will lead to harder work in the future. Better always set `value2` and check if it's `value2 != null`.

Comment: I am using a third-party library that takes some action if value2 is set. The examples show it not being set at all, if you don't want that action to be taken. I don't know what the library tests for, so I am not going to set it.

Comment: Okey, now after adding this information, that makes sense. I edited my answer and this time it should fit your requirements. If not, please let me now what's wrong and I will find a better solution for you.